# Can you copy property or constructor-arg values from objects in Spring.NET XML?

Tags: xml, spring.net, business-logic

I believe I came across this a couple months ago, but now I'm having trouble finding the answer.  Perhaps someone can just point me to the right section in the [documentation](http://springframework.net/documentation.html)?

Using [Sprint.NET](http://springframework.net/), I'm combining remote XML files into a single application context where the engine objects are separate from the business rule objects.  The problem is some of the business rules are values, not objects, which are needed by `<property>` and `<constructor-arg>` nodes in the engine xml:

```
<object name="Engine">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="business rule" />
</object>
```

Either referencing a property of another object (use `expression` attribute instead of `value`?) or perhaps some specialized name/value list (e.g. Spring's version of to `<appsettings>`, whatever that is) would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!  Starting on page 41 of the Spring Framework (Version 1.2.0 M1) PDF in "The IoC container" chapter:

> 5.3.8. Setting a reference using the members of other objects and classes.
>
> This section details those
>   configuration scenarios that involve
>   the setting of properties and
>   constructor arguments using the
>   members of other objects and classes.
>   This kind of scenario is quite common,
>   especially when dealing with legacy
>   classes that you cannot (or won't)
>   change to accommodate some of
>   Spring.NET's conventions... consider
>   the case of a class that has a
>   constructor argument that can only be
>   calculated by going to say, a
>   database. The
>   MethodInvokingFactoryObject handles
>   exactly this scenario ... it will
>   allow you to inject the result of an
>   arbitrary method invocation into a
>   constructor (as an argument) or as the
>   value of a property setter. Similarly,
>   PropertyRetrievingFactoryObject and
>   FieldRetrievingFactoryObject allow you
>   to retrieve values from another
>   object's property or field value.
>   These classes implement the
>   IFactoryObject interface which
>   indicates to Spring.NET that this
>   object is itself a factory and the
>   factories product, not the factory
>   itself, is what will be associated
>   with the object id. Factory objects
>   are discussed further in ???

This is 5.3.9.1 in the [latest online documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-advancedproperty-setting).